# Prevent "ssi_function=something" from bypassing normal control flow

Tags: php, smf-forum

If you're familiar with SMF, this is how you normally use its server side include:

```
//foo.php at http://example/foo.php
<?php
require('./SSI.php'); //assuming we're at SMF's root

//...
?>
```

But it's hidden to the untrained eye that accessing `http://example/foo.php?ssi_function=something` [will cause `ssi_something` to be called inside `SSI.php`](https://github.com/SimpleMachines/SMF2.1/blob/release-2.1/SSI.php#L180-L187), effectively bypassing the `foo.php`'s normal behaviour.

I could prepend this before `require`, but I could avoid a redirection:

```
if(isset($_GET['ssi_function']))
{
    unset($_GET['ssi_function']);
    return header('Location: ?' . http_build_query($_GET));
}
```

I have already opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SimpleMachines/SMF2.1/issues/4034), but what other options do I have to counter this nuisance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in [#4038](https://github.com/SimpleMachines/SMF2.1/pull/4038).

```
@@ -177,6 +177,9 @@
 // Have the ability to easily add functions to SSI.
 call_integration_hook('integrate_SSI');

+// Ignore a call to ssi_* functions if we are not using SSI.php
+if (empty($modSettings['allow_ssi_functions_anywhere']) && isset($_GET['ssi_function']) && basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !== 'SSI.php')
+   unset($_GET['ssi_function']);
 // Call a function passed by GET.
 if (isset($_GET['ssi_function']) && function_exists('ssi_' . $_GET['ssi_function']) && (!empty($modSettings['allow_guestAccess']) || !$user_info['is_guest']))
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this is an implementation dependent behavior within SMF. You don't need to do a redirection in this case, as the `$_GET` superglobal is mutable, simply removing the `ssi_function` parameter should be enough.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. `unset($_GET['ssi_function']);` before `require` does remove `ssi_function`, but only from `foo.php`'s scope. It still exists inside `SSI.php`.

Comment: Keep in mind you can still modify SMF to remove this behavior if you don't require it.

Comment: I know, but I'm refraining from doing so. I'll be damned if I have to mod SMF just to prevent this nuisance when all I want is to access the user system.

Comment: Sometimes you can't work around badly designed systems, if SMF exposes this functionality without a method to disable it you'll have to mod SMF. It's not exactly a problem with PHP itself.